# do the number of primes of the form 6x+1 never exceed the number of the form 6x-1 ( for all x greater than 0 )?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

All primes greater than, or equal to 5 can be expressed in either the form 6x-1 or 6x+1.
I have gone through the first 452 prime numbers ( thanks to the coronavirus lockdown! ) and kept a running total of each form. The number taking the form 6x+1 never exceed those taking the form 6x-1.
The totals equalize on nine occasions, and on each occasion the next prime number takes the form 6x-1.

will this always be the case or has such a thing been disproved?
Here is the start of my workings, just to labour the point:

nth prime      6x-1      6x+1       Sum(6x-1)      Sum(6x+1)      Diff

3              5                    1              0              1
4                        7          1              1              0
5              11                   2              1              1
6                        13         2              2              0
7              17                   3              2              1
8                        19         3              3              0
9              23                   4              3              1
10             29                   5              3              2
11                       31         5              4              1
12                       37         5              5              0
13             41                   6              5              1

452           3191                                                10

Comment: [Chebyshev bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias)

Comment: $6n+1$ takes the lead first at $\pi(608981813029)$ so a long way for your computations to go

Answer (score 5):

This is the same as asking whether the primes equal to $1\bmod 3$ ever exceed the primes equal to $2\bmod 3$. The answer is surprising: the lead in this "prime number race" changes hands infintely often, as was proven by J.E. Littlewood in 1914. The first changeover occurrs at $608981813029$.

See [this article](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf) for a gentle introduction and more info.

Comment: This sounds like having to toss a coin over half a trillion times before the number of heads exceeds the number of tails. I don't just find that surprising, I find it mind blowing!